# How do I use HTML in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, html, visual-studio-2017

First time posting on SO.
I'm brand new to the coding game (3 days old).

I'm learning CPython in Visual Studio 2017 right now and would like to play with HTML in VS2017 but I can't figure out how to start that.

I've added "QuickApp - ASP.net" - read somewhere that I needed to do that.
And I've added "HTML Application with Typescript" - Also read that I needed that.

Not sure what to do from here as I'm not able to open anything.

Thank you and I'm looking forward to being a part of this community.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're struggling with, so in order for us to help you better, can you please update your question to clearly state where you are struggling. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask], before posting your next question here. Neither *How do I use HTML* or *How do I play with HTML* is a meaningful or specific question.

Comment: To play with html you dont need Visual studio. You can use other IDE or text editors. such as notepadd++ or visual studio code both are free and light.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. Sonicbhoc suggested exactly what I was looking for. Thanks KS again for all your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you might be better off using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for web development, unless you are specifically going to start an ASP.NET project.

If you want to start an ASP.NET project, [Microsoft's MSDN page for ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/) is the best place to start learning.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate you taking the time to help out and answer this.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, then! Click the green check mark next to my answer to do so. And welcome to Stack Overflow.